# JProfiler Could not execute kubectl executable

Tags: java, kubernetes, profiling, jprofiler

When trying to execute profiling on a kubernetes cluster with JProfiler (13.0 build 13073) for macOS

"Could not execute kubectl executable" is thrown

Cannot run program ""/usr/local/Cellar/kubernetes-cli/1.23.4/bin/kubectl"": error=2, No such file or directory (kubectl installed with homebrew)

It's the same if selecting physical file or simlink /usr/local/bin/kubectl as the value in Setup Executable > Local kubectl executable.

It's as if the entire process is in a sandbox and can't access/see the files.

Comment: Those double `"` smell to be like whatever config value provided that path inadvertently tried to quote it, and `exec` does not tolerate quote marks; however, with so little information in this question, no one can possibly help you with this non-programming question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is a bug in 13.0 and will be fixed in 13.0.1.

13.0.1 download link: https://download-gcdn.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/jprofiler_macos_13_0_1.dmg

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in 13.0 and will be fixed in 13.0.1. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build with the fix.